# Sigma Notation, Multiplication

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I've recently been introduced to sigma notation, and I'm aware that $\sum (f(x) + g(x)) = \sum f(x) + \sum g(x)$. Though what is $\sum f(x)g(x)=?$

Can this be simplified similar to above? Furthermore, if I have $\sum (f(x))^2$ can it be simplified further?

I've asked my teacher, though they don't know. I've also looked online, though have been unsuccessful in finding any information on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are multiplied together in the summand as you have written: $\sum f(x)g(x)$ there is no rule that applies to simplify it unlike the former case where you distributed them over addition. The same reasoning applies to $\sum (f(x))^2$ since this is still just two functions multiplied together: $\sum f(x)f(x)$.

This probably explains why your teacher doesn't know either.